# Matrix Translation

Tags: javascript, linear-algebra, vector-multiplication

I am trying to use a createTranslation function to translate a vector. This must pass a jasmine test.

my matrix object:

```
/*global it, describe, expect, Vector, Matrix*/
/// <reference path="../js/vector.js"/>
/// <reference path="../js/matrix.js"/>
/// <reference path="../Scripts/jasmine.js"/>

var Matrix = (function () {
function Matrix(pX0, pX1, pX2, pY0, pY1, pY2, pZ0, pZ1, pZ2) {

    this.matrix = [
        [pX0, pX1, pX2],
        [pY0, pY1, pY2],
        [pZ0, pZ1, pZ2]
    ];
}
Matrix.prototype.getX0 = function () {
    return this.mX0;
};
Matrix.prototype.setX0 = function (pX0) {
    this.mX0 = pX0;
};
Matrix.prototype.getX1 = function () {
    return this.mX1;
};
Matrix.prototype.setX1 = function (pX1) {
    this.mX1 = pX1;
};
Matrix.prototype.getX2 = function () {
    return this.mX2;
};
Matrix.prototype.setX2 = function (pX2) {
    this.mX2 = pX2;
};


Matrix.prototype.getY0 = function () {
    return this.mY0;
};
Matrix.prototype.setY0 = function (pY0) {
    this.mY0 = pY0;
};
Matrix.prototype.getY1 = function () {
    return this.mY1;
};
Matrix.prototype.setY1 = function (pY1) {
    this.mY1 = pY1;
};
Matrix.prototype.getY2 = function () {
    return this.mY2;
};
Matrix.prototype.setY2 = function (pY2) {
    this.mY2 = pY2;
};


Matrix.prototype.getZ0 = function () {
    return this.mZ0;
};
Matrix.prototype.setZ0 = function (pZ0) {
    this.mZ0 = pZ0;
};
Matrix.prototype.getZ1 = function () {
    return this.mZ0;
};
Matrix.prototype.setZ1 = function (pZ1) {
    this.mZ1 = pZ1;
};
Matrix.prototype.getZ2 = function () {
    return this.mZ2;
};
Matrix.prototype.setZ2 = function (pZ2) {
    this.mZ2 = pZ2;
};
Matrix.prototype.getElement = function (pRow, pColumn) {
    return this.matrix[pRow][pColumn];
};

Matrix.createIdentity = function () {
    return new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
};
Matrix.createTranslation = function (translationVector) {

    return new Matrix(1, 0, translationVector.getX(),
        0, 1, translationVector.getY(), 0, 0, 1);
};
Matrix.createScale = function (scaleVector) {

    return new Matrix(scaleVector.getX(), 0, 0,
        0, scaleVector.getY(), 0, 0, 0, 1);
};
Matrix.createRotation = function (rotation) {

    return new Matrix(Math.cos(rotation), -Math.sin(rotation), 0,
        Math.sin(rotation), Math.cos(rotation), 0, 0, 0, 1);
};

Matrix.prototype.multiplyVector = function (vector) {
    vector = new Vector();
    return new Vector(this.getX0() * vector.getX(),
        this.getX1() * vector.getY(), this.getX2() * vector.getZ(),
        this.getY0() * vector.getX(),
        this.getY1() * vector.getY(), this.getY2() * vector.getZ(),
        this.getZ0() * vector.getX(),
        this.getZ1() * vector.getY(), this.getZ2() * vector.getZ());
};

Matrix.prototype.multiply = function (secMatrix) {
    secMatrix =  this.matrix();
    return new Matrix(this.getX0 * secMatrix.getX0,
        this.getX1 * secMatrix.getY0,
        this.getX2 * secMatrix.getZ0,
        this.getY0 * secMatrix.getX1,
        this.getY1 * secMatrix.getY1,
        this.getY2 * secMatrix.getZ1,
        this.getZ0 * secMatrix.getX2,
        this.getZ1 * secMatrix.getY2,
        this.getZ2 * secMatrix.getZ2);

};
//Matrix.prototype.multiplyVector = function (translationVector,
//secondVector, vector) {

//    return new Vector(this.getX0 * Matrix.createTranslation(translationVector),
//        this.getX1 * Matrix.createTranslation(translationVector),
//        this.getX2 * Matrix.createTranslation(translationVector),
//        this.getY0 * Matrix.createTranslation(translationVector),
//        this.getY1 * Matrix.createTranslation(translationVector),
//        this.getY2 * Matrix.createTranslation(translationVector),
//        this.getZ0 * Matrix.createTranslation(translationVector),
//        this.getZ1 * Matrix.createTranslation(translationVector),
//        this.getZ2 * Matrix.createTranslation(translationVector));
//};
Matrix.prototype.multiplyVectors = function (translationVector,
    vector, secondVector) {

    return new Vector(vector.getX() * Matrix.createTranslation(translationVector),
        vector.getY() * Matrix.createTranslation(translationVector),
        vector.getZ() * Matrix.createTranslation(translationVector),
        secondVector = this.multiplyVector(vector));
};
//Matrix.prototype.multiply = function () {
//    return new Matrix();
//};

return Matrix;

}());
```

Commented parts are me trying different ways to achieve this.

This object has to pass the following test.

```
describe("Multiply vector", function () {
    describe("Translation", function () {
        var vector, translationVector, matrix, secondVector;
        vector = new Vector(30, 40, 1);
        translationVector = new Vector(10, 20, 1);
        matrix = Matrix.createTranslation(translationVector);
        secondVector = matrix.multiplyVector(vector);
        it("X Set", function () {
            expect(secondVector.getX()).toEqual(40);
        });

        it("Y Set", function () {
            expect(secondVector.getY()).toEqual(60);
        });

        it("Z Set", function () {
            expect(secondVector.getZ()).toEqual(1);
        });
    });
    describe("Rotation", function () {
        var vector, rotation, matrix, secondVector;
        vector = new Vector(30, 40, 1);
        rotation = Math.PI / 2;
        matrix = Matrix.createRotation(rotation);
        secondVector = matrix.multiplyVector(vector);
        it("X Set", function () {
            expect(secondVector.getX()).toBeCloseTo(-40, 1);
        });

        it("Y Set", function () {
            expect(secondVector.getY()).toBeCloseTo(30, 1);
        });

        it("Z Set", function () {
            expect(secondVector.getZ()).toBeCloseTo(1, 1);
        });
    });
    describe("Scale", function () {
        var vector, scaleVector, matrix, secondVector;
        vector = new Vector(30, 40, 1);
        scaleVector = new Vector(2, 2, 1);
        matrix = Matrix.createScale(scaleVector);
        secondVector = matrix.multiplyVector(vector);
        it("X Set", function () {
            expect(secondVector.getX()).toEqual(60);
        });

        it("Y Set", function () {
            expect(secondVector.getY()).toEqual(80);
        });

        it("Z Set", function () {
            expect(secondVector.getZ()).toEqual(1);
        });
    });
});
```

There are other tests for rotation but once I figure out this one the rest will follow.

I am a little stuck on this as I am unsure of what I need to do, do I create more functions for each the translate, rotate, scale or is it possible to have it all in the multiplyVector function?

EDIT:

```
Matrix.prototype.multiplyVector = function (translationVector) {

    return new Vector(Matrix.createTranslation().getX0 *        translationVector.getX() +
           Matrix.createTranslation().getX1 * translationVector.getY() +
           Matrix.createTranslation().getX2 * translationVector.getZ(),
           Matrix.createTranslation().getY0 * translationVector.getX() +
           Matrix.createTranslation().getY1 * translationVector.getY() +
           Matrix.createTranslation().getY2 * translationVector.getZ(),
           Matrix.createTranslation().getZ0 * translationVector.getX() +
           Matrix.createTranslation().getZ1 * translationVector.getY() +
           Matrix.createTranslation().getZ2 * translationVector.getZ());

};
```

I have tried to do it this way but still it is not working.

Comment: The `multiplyVector` function's only purpose is to multiply a matrix by a vector, is it not? Are you supposed to be embedding all this hidden functionality within it? What is the actual problem here?

Comment: I think that aswell, but like all the tests given they include the name of the function such as multiplyVector, and not multiplyVectorTranslate. I was wondering if I need to have a new function for each Translate, rotate and scale or is is possible to multiply the vector and include the translate, rotate and scale operations in the single MultiplyVector function.

Comment: The matrices that call `multiplyVector` already have the translation/rotation/scale data within them. Multiplying a vector by a transformation matrix is how you apply the transformation to the vector. If you re-generate the transformations inside the function, you are going to get incorrect results.

Comment: `Matrix.prototype.multiplyVector = function (translationVector) {

        return new Vector(Matrix.createTranslation().getX0 * translationVector.getX() +
            Matrix.createTranslation().getX1 * translationVector.getY() +
            Matrix.createTranslation().getX2 * translationVector.getZ());
    };`  So something like this, but continued for getY and getZ?

Comment: See [this image](http://polymathprogrammer.com/images/blog/200808/matrixvectormultiplication.png) ([source article](http://polymathprogrammer.com/2008/08/11/matrices-for-programmers/))

Comment: I had a look and saw that I needed the row vector X matrix and changed it to that but even then it is not passing the test.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example as described at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track with the code in your edit, but like I said in the comments, the matrix you are multiplying with the vector already has the transformation info within it. Not only do you not need to generate it again, but doing so will alter the transformation data to the point where you will get the wrong output.

The resource that qxz provided:

[image]

is the correct way to multiply a matrix by a column vector. To implement it in code, you do the following:

```
Matrix.prototype.multiplyVector = function(vector) {
    return new Vector(
        this.getX0() * vector.getX() + this.getX1() * vector.getY() + this.getX2() * vector.getZ(),
        this.getY0() * vector.getX() + this.getY1() * vector.getY() + this.getY2() * vector.getZ(),
        this.getZ0() * vector.getX() + this.getZ1() * vector.getY() + this.getZ2() * vector.getZ()
    );
}
```